# Please give the solution to that

Tags: perl, tcl

I am calling a function and passing 3 parameters to that. I am taking each parameter one be one and performing some operations on that. At the end i am traversing the loop so as to perform the same operations on the rest of the parameters.

Suppose the problem is like this:

```
print "Starting the operations";
# calling the function say NetworkMode
NetworkMode(SONET,SDH,SDH-J)   #This will perform certain steps
print "Ending of the test case"
```

Output i want should come like this:

```
#Starting the operaions
#Whatever the output function will give using first parameter
#Ending the test case
#Starting the operaions
#Whatever the output function will give using second parameter
#Ending the test case
#Starting the operaions
#Whatever the output function will give using third parameter
#Ending the test case
```

Is there any way i can do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call one single function [once], then you get one chance to print out a result; if you want to print out once per parameter, then the function itself is going to have to do the printing out as it operates on each parameter. If, however, you're repeating the exact same steps on each parameter then perhaps your function should only take one parameter?

Comment: It means i have to  call the function thrice one parameter each time

Comment: Correct - then you can print out the result once for each call. If you *have* to pass all parameters at once, then the printing has to be done within the function.

Answer (score 2):

You mean that the `NetworkMode` function actually takes only one parameter? If so, then this code will probably do what you want:

```
foreach my $mode (SONET, SDH, SDH-J)
{
    print "Starting the operations";
    # calling the function say NetworkMode
    NetworkMode($mode);   #This will perform certain steps
    print "Ending of the test case";
}
```

Comment: means there is no other way. is there any way the function shouls come out and print these lines and again enter into the funciton

Comment: The first line (the loop) means exactly that: do _something_ several times, _something_ being your small program. If, later, you want to add some modes, add them in the loop.

Comment: If you want a function to call externally-controlled code rather than have the logic inside, then that would normally be achieved by passing the address of a callback function that you call from within the function to do the logging. Not sure if that can be done in PHP, so go with Stamm's suggestion.